# How to access a class variable shadowed by an instance variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I couldn't find a specific answer to my question. As you might know, a class in Python can have both class variables and instance variables. If a class has a class variable and an instance variable that both have the same name, how can I access both in another method of the class?

Suppose the following code. How can I access both variables `myvar`?

```
class myclass:
    myvar = "class variable"

    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = "instance variable"
        pass

    def test(self):
        # difference between self.myvar and myclass.myvar
        return self.myvar


class_instance = myclass()
print(class_instance.test())
print(class_instance.myvar)     # "class variable" or "instance variable"
```

Here if I remove `myvar` from `__init__` the `self.myvar` would refer to the class variable and if I add it, `self.myvar` would refer to the instance variable. So is it a rule that instance variables have precedence over class variable? I know that I can use `myclass.myvar` for referring to the class member, but in the last line of the above code `class_instance.myvar` would refer to both class variable and instance variable.

Comment: Is your question about accessing them inside methods or from the caller?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank Both of them.

Comment: 'some_class' is not a class, but an instance of 'myclass'

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suppose you are using Python 3. If that was not the case, you should change the first line to read: `class myclass(object)`

To access the instance variable, you can use: `class_instance.myvar`

To access the class variable, you can use: `type(class_instance).myvar`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to get the class variable is access the class:

```
print(some_class.test2())
print(myclass.myvar)
```

Or, if you dont have the class in scope:

```
print(some_class.test2())
print(type(someclass).myvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are instantiating the class,

```
some_class = myclass()
```

you are basically overwriting the myvar value (when the `__init__` constructor is called)

You can observe by using this code -

```
class myclass:
    myvar = "class variable"
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.myvar) #added a print statement
        self.myvar = "instance variable"
        pass
    def test(self):
        # difference between self.myvar and myclass.myvar
        return self.myvar


class_instance = myclass() 
print(class_instance.test())
print(class_instance.myvar)
```

Output is -

```
class variable #due to print command
instance variable #command called after the overwriting of myvar variable
instance variable #command called after the overwriting of myvar variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate I've seen another way of finding this, and when I've seen that, you have come to my mind and I wanted to share it with you, because, I thought like, you might be searching for this solution:

With code that've written below you can reach both same named variables with underscoring first one.

```
   class myclass:
    __myvar = "class variable"
    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = "instance variable"
        pass
    def test(self):
        # difference between self.myvar and myclass.myvar
        return self.myvar


class_instance = myclass() 
print(class_instance.test())
print(class_instance._myclass__myvar)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class myclass:
    myvar = "class variable"

    def __init__(self):
        self.myvar = "instance variable"
        pass
    def test2(self):
        return myclass.myvar


some_class = myclass()
print(some_class.test2())
print(some_class.myvar)
```

This might help you! We are finding both of them :)

Comment: You changed the code in `test2`. Why do you think this is an answer?

Comment: Aren't we wanting to show both of them, even while they are in the same names? Then this is the solution? No?

Comment: @M.AliÖztürk It is obvious that you can directly refer to a class member. But when saying `self.myvar` it can be referred to both class and instance variables, this is my question.

Comment: Could you explain why do you search for another solution than this obvious one?
And I couldn't find a way to do what you said, I'll also learn with u(ofc if there is one)

Comment: @M.AliÖztürk I think there might be a reason behind this.